# How can I solve my AMDGPU drivers problem?

Tags: drivers, 20.04, kernel, amdgpu, amdgpu-pro

I am running Ubuntu 20.04 on kernel 5.8.0-49 with dual monitors and have an AMD RX 5600XT card.

My problem is that Ubuntu has a very, very slow boot up and a wild screen flickering when I am logged in.
`dmesg` clearly shows that the slow boot times are due to following errors:

```
[   19.535515] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sr0, sector 16324608 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 2 prio class 0
[   19.535519] Buffer I/O error on dev sr0, logical block 4081152, async page read
[   19.535521] Buffer I/O error on dev sr0, logical block 4081153, async page read
[   19.537684] [drm] Cannot allocate secure buffer since TMZ is disabled
[   22.719743] amdgpu: Msg issuing pre-check failed and SMU may be not in the right state!
[   25.993286] amdgpu: Msg issuing pre-check failed and SMU may be not in the right state!
[   29.265644] amdgpu: Msg issuing pre-check failed and SMU may be not in the right state!
[   32.535781] amdgpu: Msg issuing pre-check failed and SMU may be not in the right state!
[   33.401404] rfkill: input handler disabled
[   36.701544] amdgpu: Msg issuing pre-check failed and SMU may be not in the right state!
[   39.909124] amdgpu: Msg issuing pre-check failed and SMU may be not in the right state!
[   43.179987] amdgpu: Msg issuing pre-check failed and SMU may be not in the right state!
[   46.452572] amdgpu: Msg issuing pre-check failed and SMU may be not in the right state!
[   49.727429] amdgpu: Msg issuing pre-check failed and SMU may be not in the right state!
[   53.002104] amdgpu: Msg issuing pre-check failed and SMU may be not in the right state!
[  128.063620] logitech-hidpp-device 0003:046D:4088.0008: HID++ 4.5 device connected.
```

I have a video of the flickering as well as the full `dmesg` ouput at the end of the post.

My problem is completely gone when I only use one of my two monitors (unplug it from the GPU). The monitors are connected via DisplayPort and have a 60 Hz frequency as well as WQHD resolution.

#### What I have tried so far without luck:

1. Upgrading the Kernel to 5.11.13
2. Downgrading the Kernel to 5.4.111
3. Manually installing the `amdgpu-pro` drivers from the AMD website for Ubuntu 20.04.2 version 20.50
4. Changing to Wayland
5. Deactivating `Above 4G decoding` in the UEFI

---

Find the full `dmesg` [here](https://pastebin.com/bvrXEtwi) and the video [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9OwEX.jpg).

Comment: Me too. Pls, help. Had linux mint 20.1. Video stopped working with some update. Changed into ubuntu 20.04 (erasing everything in the process) and the exact same problem (black screen) happening. I have RADEON RX 560 (which is not one of the latest). How come it does not work? And we have tried a bunch of alternatives.... Can only do anything with recovery mode (which is a pain to get to and exhausts your cpu totally).

Comment: See comments 13-16 on this [bug](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=208893). Slightly different setup, but maybe... because matches OP's error message, flickering, and two monitors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used 2x 27" WQHD Iiyama XUB2792QSU screens that seem to be the problem.

I did buy 2 new AOC screens, 4K this time, and they do not produce the same bug.